# How to select values with latest date when some values are repeated and others do not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server with two columns where some of the values are repeated in one.
The output should have `Host Order` unique with the latest date from `Create Date`

```
Host Order  Create Date
02600679    8/13/19
02608969    9/2/19
02608969    8/20/19
02609573    8/30/19
02611960    8/27/19
02611960    8/23/19
02612117    8/26/19
```

Output

```
  Host Order    Create Date
    02600679    8/13/19
    02608969    9/2/19
    02609573    8/30/19
    02611960    8/27/19
    02612117    8/26/19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select [host order], max([create date])
from your_table
group by [host order]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How add multiple columns in the query? I wanted to return more columns with this query as well

Comment: If you want to `select` more columns then you also have to add them in your `group by` clause.

Comment: Again thanks a lot !. I stuck on it like over an hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the full row, then a correlated subquery or `row_number()` is what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.createdate = (select max(t2.createdate) from t t2 where t2.host = t.host);
```